Реверс прокси сервер для докера, с помою Traefik
Есть такая проблема с реверс прокси сервером, созданным traefik.
Есть контейнер для node socket сервера, и контейнер трафика, который должен обеспечить внешний доступ к сокет серверу.
Вот такая конфигурация для docker compose
version: '3.9'

services:
  app-mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: app-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: beauty
    volumes:
      - app-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - /var/www/smart-beauty/beauty.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/beauty.sql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - app-network

  node-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: node-app
    expose:
      - "80"
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      DB_HOST: "app-mysql"
      DB_PORT: "3306"
      DB_USER: "root"
      DB_PASSWORD: "root"
      DB_NAME: "beauty"
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - app-mysql
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.node-app.rule=Host(`mynodeapp.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.node-app.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.node-app.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.node-app.tls=false"
      - "traefik.docker.network=app-network"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.node-app.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-For=X-Real-IP"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.node-app.headers.customrequestheaders.Upgrade=websocket"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.node-app.headers.customrequestheaders.Connection=Upgrade"
      - "traefik.http.routers.node-app.middlewares=node-app"
      - "traefik.constraint-label=app-network"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--accesslog"
      - "--accesslog.filepath=/var/log/traefik/access.log"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  app-mysql:

Все контейнеры нормально создаются, из нутри каждого контейнера доступ к другому есть, и там никаких проблем нету, пинки идут, все как бы хорошо.
Но когда снаруже по доменному имени хочу получить доступ к нод серверу вылезает ошибка 502 Bad Gateway' caused by: EOF
А вот часть лога трафика, если это поможет разобраться
  traefik    | time="2024-12-23T05:56:39Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=web middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
  traefik    | time="2024-12-23T05:56:39Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware dashboard@internal" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal
  traefik    | time="2024-12-23T05:56:39Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal middlewareType=StripPrefix
  traefik    | time="2024-12-23T05:56:39Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal
  traefik    | time="2024-12-23T05:56:39Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik
  traefik    | time="2024-12-23T05:56:39Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection from ^(http:\\/\\/(\\[[\\w:.]+\\]|[\\w\\._-]+)(:\\d+)?)\\/$ to ${1}/dashboard/" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik
  traefik    | time="2024-12-23T05:56:39Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal entryPointName=traefik
  traefik    | time="2024-12-23T05:56:39Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware api@internal" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=traefik routerName=api@internal

Кто может помоч понять причину. Буду благодарен.

У вас compose сеть переименовывает, попробуйте настройку traefik.docker.network убрать. Ну и доступ к сокету нужен rw, как вы представляете отправку HTTP-запроса от траефика к докеру через read-only сокет?

Кстати, уберите все эти заголовки Upgrade и Connection, траефик умеет правильно пробрасывать веб-сокеты из коробки.

@PavelMayorov Изменил на rw, убрал то что сказали, но та же проблема, но контейнер трафика видит другой, пинги идут.
